# Android passing the parcelable object List between activities

Tags: android, parameter-passing, parcelable

My problem is after i pass the list to second activity i can not cast it to list back. Its crashing app.I tried with try catch but still no exception. Any idea what im doing wrong ? Tyvm.

Activity 1

```
 private ArrayList<ResimBean> rbList = new ArrayList<ResimBean>();

 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResimListActivity.class);
 intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("reslist",rbList);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

Activity 2

```
 private ArrayList<ResimBean> rbList = new ArrayList<ResimBean>();


if (extras != null) {
            try {

                Intent i = getIntent();
                rbList = (ArrayList<ResimBean>)i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("reslist");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                String msg = ex.getMessage();
            }

        }
```

And My Class

```
public class ResimBean implements Parcelable {

    private int Id;
    private int HataBildirimId;
    private byte[] Resim;
    private byte[] Thumbnail;

    public byte[] getThumbnail() {
        return Thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(byte[] thumbnail) {
        Thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    private String Path;

    public String getPath() {
        return Path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        Path = path;
    }

    public int getHataBildirimId() {
        return HataBildirimId;
    }

    public void setHataBildirimId(int hataBildirimId) {
        HataBildirimId = hataBildirimId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public byte[] getResim() {
        return Resim;
    }

    public void setResim(byte[] resim) {
        Resim = resim;
    }
 @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
  @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(HataBildirimId);
        dest.writeByteArray(Resim);
        dest.writeByteArray(Thumbnail);

    }
    public ResimBean(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in){
        this.HataBildirimId = in.readInt();
        this.Resim = new byte[in.readInt()];
        this.Thumbnail = new byte[in.readInt()];
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ResimBean> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ResimBean>() {
        @Override
        public ResimBean createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ResimBean(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ResimBean[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ResimBean[size];
        }
    };
}
```

***EDIT***
I changed to `rbList = i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("reslist");` but its still crashing.

***EDIT 2***
Here my logcat error.

```
04-12 10:27:34.786: E/Surface(9374): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa5d110d0
```

***EDIT 3***
Here how i populate the list

```
   Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] thumbArray = stream.toByteArray();

            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bmp);
            String picPath = getRealPathFromURI(tempUri);
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picPath);
            byte[] bar = getBytesFromBitmap(yourSelectedImage);

            ResimBean rb = new ResimBean(Parcel.obtain());

            rb.setResim(bar);
            rb.setThumbnail(thumbArray);
            rb.setPath(picPath);
            rbList.add(rb);
```

Comment: why do you call `getSerializableExtra`?

Comment: Your are passing as putParcelableArrayListExtra and access as Serializaable Extra   which is wrong use either one

Comment: so i tried     rbList = i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("reslist"); but still crashing

Comment: still crashing? how crashing?

Comment: not droping to catch its closing the app instantly

Comment: @keikoman post your logcat.

Comment: post your logcat then

Comment: 04-12 10:27:34.786: E/Surface(9374): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa5d110d0
its the only logcat error

Comment: Are you on Marshmallow (6.0)?

Comment: you want particular object or whole list??

Comment: @RohitArya yes  im on 6.0

Comment: @jankigadhiya i need whole list

Comment: Okay, Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565751/android-passing-the-parcelable-object-list-between-activities/36566594#36566594)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Error log added (`E/Surface(9374): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa5d110d0`):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192357) in Marshmallow (6.0). And it has been fixed in 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

```
 rbList = (ArrayList<ResimBean>)i.getSerializableExtra("reslist");
```

here is problem in code you passing parcelable and fetching serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Your are passing as `putParcelableArrayListExtra` and access as `getSerializableExtra` Extra which is wrong

Replace

rbList = (ArrayList)i.getSerializableExtra("reslist");

with

rbList = i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("reslist");

Answer (score 0):

You pass data from Activity1 to Activity2. Why? You use startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

Try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResimListActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("reslist",rbList);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: sry about my chicken english level :(  i wont mean that